# Is there any direct API to duplicate a PHAsset?

Tags: ios, phasset, photosframework

As a workaround, I am fetching the image data of that PHAsset and then writing it again to create a duplicate asset. But this seems to be expensive and makes the code dirty. Is there any Direct API for this?

Does Apple provide any direct API to make a copy of a PHAsset?

Comment: You mean Let newAsset = oldAsset  ?

Comment: No, I want to create a copy of an image and save it as a new image in Photos app.